# What is the genus of compact Riemann surface: $\Sigma =\{[X,Y,Z]\in \mathbb{C}P^2: Z^2=XY\}.$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

> What is the genus of compact Riemann surface: $$\Sigma =\{[X,Y,Z]\in \mathbb{C}P^2: Z^2=XY\}.$$

I try to use the Riemann-Herwitz Formula $f: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{S},$
we have $$2g(\Sigma)-2=B_{p}(f)-2\deg(f),$$
where $g(\cdot)$ means the genus and $B_{p}(f)$ is the branch number of $f$ at point $p$.

I know how to calculate the genus of $\Sigma=\{[X,Y,Z]\in \mathbb{C}P^2: X+Y+Z=0\}$, but how to get the genus of a nonlinear polynomial $\Sigma =\{[X,Y,Z]\in \mathbb{C}P^2: Z^2=XY\}?$

Comment: Your $\Sigma$ is the embedding of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ into $\mathbb{CP}^2$ under the second Veronese embedding.

Comment: @KennyWong Sorry, I do not know the second Veronese embedding.

Comment: Consider $f : \mathbb {CP^1} \to \mathbb {CP}^2$ given by $f([u:v]) = [u^2 : v^2 : uv]$. What is its image?

Comment: You said you tried to use the Riemann-Hurwitz formula. Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: The point is to apply Riemann-Hurwitz by projecting from a point onto a line, so that you express $\Sigma$ as a branched cover of the line. In other words, you consider the $1$-parameter family of lines through a fixed point. All but two of these lines meet $\Sigma$ transversely in a pair of points; the two remaining lines are tangent to $\Sigma$ and meet it at a single point. So you should get $-2$ on the right hand side of the formula, showing that $g(\Sigma) = 0$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Sorry, I do not understand. How about the degree of $f$ and branch number of $\infty$? How many branch points? Is it just one point $\infty$?

Comment: @KennyWong Do you mean $f: [u,v] \mapsto [u^2,v^2,uv]$? Then the degree of $f$ is 2 and the branch point is only $\infty$?